# Creating matrix widget

Tags: azure-devops

In my organization we recently moved to Azure DevOps and at this point we are configuring dashboards to monitor what is happening in the environments.

I would like to create a matrix widget where Y would be Release Piplelines and X would be the environments we have.

In the table I would like to have all the images that are on a particular environment at the moment.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Release pipeline overview` widget to your azure devops dashboards. With this widget, you can view and track the status of a release pipeline. it shows the release as a series of environments, with the name of the release and the date or time it was started.

Go the **DashBoards** under **Overview** in your azure devops project portal. Click **Edit** and search for `Release pipeline overview` widget. Then configure the Release pipeline to be displayed on the dashboard. The widget looks like below screenshot. It might not be exactly what you want. But it is most closest one i can find in azure devops extension market.

If you would like to create your own widget. You can refer to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops) provided in microsoft official site

[image]

If you want to view and track the status of multiple Release pipelines. You can add multiple `Release pipeline overview` widgets one for each of them.

Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#release-pipeline-overview) to explore more other widgets. Hope above helps!